# proj4js gives wrong result for EPSG:3375

Tags: javascript, proj, proj4js

Faced with very strange issue. Trying to do coordinate transformation from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3375 using proj4js and getting wrong result.

This is my code:

```
var epsg4326 = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'

var epsg3375 = '+proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=102.25 +alpha=323.0257964666666 +k=0.99984 +x_0=804671 +y_0=0 +no_uoff +gamma=323.1301023611111 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs'

var transformation = proj4(epsg4326, epsg3375)
var input = [101.70979078430528, 3.06268465621428];
var output = transformation.forward(input);
// 744626.6428051005, -103618.62269607143
// expected: 412597.532715, 338944.957259
```

This is a [JSFiddle workspace](https://jsfiddle.net/3sc1zejb/17/) for live demo of the issue.

I have created [an issue](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/273) at the proj4js github repo.

Any ideas on that?

Could you please suggest alternative JS libraries I can use to do this transformation in browser? It looks like many other libraries depends on proj4js which is not perfect as I found out.

Comment: What parameter is `+lonc=`?

Comment: According to proj4.org it is "? Longitude used with Oblique Mercator and possibly a few others" (http://proj4.org/parameters.html)

Comment: Yes, found it and repeated your transformation with GDAL 2.3.0dev. I got the expected result `412597.532715331 338944.957259175`. Feels really like a bug in proj4js.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, it doesn't appear that proj4.js can handle oblique mercator (ignores the alpha value).

Comment: It's the classic issue of Hotine variant A and B. see e.g. https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/104. and https://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XLII-4-W16/123/2019/isprs-archives-XLII-4-W16-123-2019.pdf.